# How do we find the length of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I dont see how we can find the length of an object. For arrays i can your `array.length` but it doesnt work for objects, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `Object.keys(myObj).length`

Comment: Why do you need to know the length of an object? What would you do with that?

Answer (score 1):

Just like that:

```js
Object.keys(objectName).length;
```